# Itnelij не видит spring context

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Itnelij не видит spring context. Ссылки http://www.springframework.org/schema/context, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd Intelij подчёркивает красным и выдаёт ошибку. Хотя ссылки рабочие. Пытался добавить s в http но не сработало

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, чтобы в зависимостях maven был spring-context. Правой кнопкой мыши-Maven-Show dependencies tree. Если spring-context там нет, то надо добавить в pom.xml зависимость:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```